# How to send a request with current coverage in post-Integration script using Xcode Server?

Tags: xcode, bash, continuous-integration, xcode-server

I setup a bot to perform my continuous integration. But I need to send info about coverage to my database using its own API.

Using following address: `http://lb.mycompany.org/api/public/metrics` I need to send a POST with following parameters:

```
{"project_public_id": "myprojectid", "type": "coverage", "value": "50", "platform": "ios"}
```

[image]

How can I do this? How to access code coverage from within trigger script?

Answer (score 0):

You can use, but I don't know how to get `coverage` value. Example for XCS_TESTS_COUNT:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" your_http_address -d '{"value":'$XCS_TESTS_COUNT'}'
```

Comment: You want double quotes inside the single quotes.  JSON uses double quotes around strings, and the entire JSON snippet will be in single quotes.  (This means you can't interpolate a shell variable within the JSON snippet, but that's easy to do with something like `'{"key": "value", "key2", "'"$shell_variable"'"}'`.  See further http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable